# CPU usage of CP-SAT solver with num_search_workers = 8

Tags: or-tools, cp-sat

Dears,
I have a question, If I have a 32-core CPU and use CP-SAT with num_search_workers = 8, how many CPU core am I using?
thanks

Comment: just 8 threads (at most). Do you have 32 threads or physical cores?